# How do I get the sum of all numbers in a range function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out how to take x (from code below) and add it to itself to get the sum and then divide it by the number of ratings. The example given in class was 4 ratings, with the numbers being 3,4,1,and 2. The average rating should be 2.5, but I can't seem to get it right!

```
number_of_ratings = eval(input("Enter the number of difficulty ratings as a positive integer: "))       # Get number of difficulty ratings
for i in range(number_of_ratings):      #   For each diffuculty rating
    x = eval(input("Enter the difficulty rating as a positive integer: "))      # Get next difficulty rating
average = x/number_of_ratings
print("The average diffuculty rating is: ", average)
```

Comment: You could use math for this problem. `n * (n + 1) / 2 = sum(range(n+1))`. This can be useful for large values of n.

Comment: @raz: Where do you need this formula when calculating an average?

Comment: @Philipp: Just divide into `n` (the number of items) the sum and `(n + 1) / 2 = avg(range(n + 1))`

Comment: @raz: I don't think that is what the OP wants. He wants to average over a sequence of input data, not over a Python range.

Comment: @Philipp: You're right. Sorry I didn't read the question complete. I just thought that the sum was in the range of 1 to n.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't add anything, it just overwrites `x` in each iteration. Adding something to a variable can be done with the `+=` operator. Also, don't use `eval`:

```
number_of_ratings = int(input("Enter the number of difficulty ratings as a positive integer: "))
x = 0
for i in range(number_of_ratings):
    x += int(input("Enter the difficulty rating as a positive integer: "))
average = x/number_of_ratings
print("The average diffuculty rating is: ", average)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's my first programming experience, this was a big help.

Comment: This would also be perfectly valid and a little more concise: `x = sum(int(input('Enter the difficulty rating as a positive integer: ')) for i in range(number_of_ratings))`

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    inp = raw_input
except NameError:
    inp = input

_sum = 0.0
_num = 0
while True:
    val = float(inp("Enter difficulty rating (-1 to exit): "))
    if val==-1.0:
        break
    else:
        _sum += val
        _num += 1

if _num:
    print "The average is {0:0.3f}".format(_sum/_num)
else:
    print "No values, no average possible!"
```